# Unable to perform arithmetic operation in select statement in specific scenario

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

While I was doing some multiplication in select statements, I found a special case where SQL Server is throwing an arithmetic overflow error.

When I executed the same in W3Schools SQL window, it worked. Below is my query where it is throwing error. I tried multiple permutations and combinations but it failed in most of the cases

```
SELECT 20000000 * 130
```

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Message window:

[image: SQL MESSAGE WINDOW]

Output window:

[image: SQL OUTPUT WINDOW]

Version information:

[image: SQL VERSION DESCRIPTION]

Comment: Can you share the W3Schools link with us?

Comment: Replace the text in sql window and see the output

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Answer (score 1):

type int isn't enought, try float.

```
SELECT cast(20000000 as float) * cast(130 as float)
```

The result is the data type of the argument with the higher precedence. But if you have 2 int you can't get a float without casting
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/language-elements/multiply-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

I had used float but bigint is the same

Comment: I appreciate your Intelligent approach but I am wondering then how come it could work with Next example of mine where I have BIG integer value "867686786786876876786867"

Comment: Because 867686786786876876786867 is already a bigint, while 20000000 is an int type, as i said above the result is the data type of the argument with the higher precedence, result of bigint * int = bigint, int * int = int.

Comment: You are welcome, remember to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CAST(20000000 AS BIGINT) * 130

Comment: Thanks Deep the solution is cool but why would I need to cast it to BIGINT while I am able to multiply even bigger numbers.

Comment: For big number sql consider its data type to Big Int but for your given number sql consider its data type to int but for its result  is in big int that's why its giving error.